# Loop through table rows to find duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm trying to use JS to loop through a table I have to let me know if I have a row with duplicate values. This is the function I have, my issue is I'm not sure what to do next, using each compares the first row to itself and I'm not looking for that any advice?

```
$('.active').each(function (n) {
    var type1 = $(this).attr('Order');
    $('.active').each(function (n) {
        var type2 = $(this).attr('Order');
        var type3;
        if ($(this).attr('Order') != type1) {
            type3 = $(this).attr('Order');

            if ($(this).attr('Order') == type1) {
                alert('true');
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Are you filling these tables from a data source? Because it's almost always better to deduplicate using the data source's native functionality; doing it in the DOM is going to be relatively slow, especially over thousands of rows.

Comment: Hi, Jak! Have you looped through this code yourself to see any output? If so, could you provide it and give us a more specific question? Because, I am not sure what you're after here.

Comment: Can you add some HTML to help determine exactly what `.active` and `Order=` might be

Comment: For the 2nd `.each` you could use `.nextAll()` instead, then it won't compare with itself - if you compare row 1 with row 3, you don't need to compare row 3 with row 1.